# HTTP Proxy: Squid: Logging: Where can I find the details of my http request & response body

Tags: http, logging, proxy, squid

Problem: I'm sending HTTP Requests (GET & POST) via my Squid proxy and I figured out how to log the request (`"%>h"`) and response (`"%<h"`) header into the access_log, BUT I could not figure out where I can find the details of the request and response body respective how to configure the logging to log out as well the request/response body.

I've read through different articles: https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidLogs, http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/logformat/,  etc. but could nowhere find information how to log the http request & response body into a log file.

Comment: I do not understand why this failed for you. Adding `%>h` to my logformat line worked. I wonder if it was significant that I also added the [log_mime_hdrs](https://serverfault.com/questions/87428/can-squid-http-proxy-dump-all-client-server-headers) on setting.